AG-grid export two tables to one excel sheet
I have the following:
  const gridRef = useRef<AgGridReact>(null);

  const onBtnExport = useCallback(() => {
    gridRef.current!.api.exportDataAsCsv({
      columnSeparator: ',',
      allColumns: true,
    });
  }, []);

which allows me to download grid data depending on which tab is selected:
  {isPacingPerformanceWidgetActive && activeTab === 'pacing_performance' && (
    <DashboardPacingPerformance ref={gridRef} />
  )}
  {isPublisherInsightsWidgetActive && activeTab === 'publisher_insights' && (
    <DashboardPublisherInsights ref={gridRef} />
  )}

the problem I have is that I can only download one grid at the time as gridRef will only be populated with whatever ui's data is available.
I do have access to both tables data and I would like to download them at the same time , like a global export even if one of the tables is hidden.
